# Systemd cant find my 'start.sh' file?

Tags: server, java, systemd, services, minecraft

so i am trying to get a minecraft server running as a service of systemd

my minecraft.service has this content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Minecraft Server
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/minecraft/
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/minecraft/start.sh
User=minecraft
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=inherit
RestartSec=30

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This file is placed in /lib/systemd/system/minecraft.service

if i Start this service and check the status i get:

```
EXEC '/home/minecraft/start.sh' no such file or directory
```

But this file actually exists ... 
and the file is working if i start it manually.

Ubuntu version is 18.10

after trying to head -n 1 /home/minecraft/start.sh like suggested it get:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

would be cool if someone can help :)

Comment: make sure the filename isn't different from what you have given to systemd!

Comment: i just reviewed the filenames about 10 times ^^

Comment: ok run `ls -l /home/minecraft/start.sh` and lets see the out put!

Comment: -rwxrwxr-- 1 minecraft nogroup 85 Nov 24 00:16 /home/minecraft/start.sh ... ^^

Comment: ok run `head -n 1 /home/minecraft/shart.sh`. Edit ( https://askubuntu.com/posts/1095529/edit ) your post with the results, don't comment.